# Plots not showing labels in order

Tags: r, data-science

I have following data frame:

```
      BeginTime          APName
       20:04:33      wls-wilkeson17-46
       20:20:06      wls-wilkeson17-46
       21:28:01      wls-wilkeson17-46
       21:33:10      wls-wilkeson17-46
       21:48:56      wls-wilkeson17-46
       21:59:18      wls-wilkeson17-46
       21:07:19      wls-wilkeson17-47
```

I am trying to plot it in r like this:

```
plot(x = user_sig_all$BeginTime, y = factor(user_sig_all$APName), yaxt = "n")
```

Then I am drawing labels on y axis using:

```
axis(2, at=1:7, labels=user_sig_all$APName)
```

And graph I am getting is

[image]

As you can see it is just displaying label no 1 and 2 which are wls-wilkeson17-46, but it should show wls-wilkeson17-47 for topmost point as per data.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plotting, draw your axis one by one by putting in a loop like below:

```
plot(x = user_sig_all$BeginTime, y = factor(user_sig_all$APName), yaxt = "n")
countt <- 1
last_lab <- user_sig_all$APName[1]

for (AP in user_sig_all$APName){
  if(countt == 1) {
    axis(2, at=countt:countt, labels=AP)
    last_lab <- AP
    countt <- countt + 1
  } else {
    if(last_lab != AP){
      axis(2, at=countt:countt, labels=AP)
      last_lab <- AP
      countt <- countt + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

You may mis-understand the `at` parameter in function `axis()`, which specify the unique locations at `axis(1,2,3 or 4)` of the all points. So in your case, there is only two locations at `Y_Axis`, so `at` should be `c(1, 2)`.

#### Solution:

```
axis(2, at=c(1, length(levels(user_sig_all$APName))), labels=user_sig_all$APName)
```